# exec cannot find the PHP file to execute

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am trying to call a PHP script from another PHP script using the `shell_exec` command. when I enter the same command in the shell using the same user, everything works as expected. However, when I call it in PHP I got the following output:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.23
Content-type: text/html
```

My PHP call is:

```
shell_exec('php -f /home/site/public_html/script.php > /home/site/log.txt &');
```

I check server configuration. Safe Mode is off. `shell_exec('whoami')` is working without any problem.

Comment: Perhaps the program `php` is not available or not in the `$PATH`. Try specifying the full path to the `php` binary.

Comment: I tried shell_exec('/usr/bin/php -f /home/site/public_html/script.php > /home/websity/log.txt &'); and i got the same output, also from output it seems that php is executed but couldn't find the file script.php

Comment: `/usr/bin/php` exists?

Comment: yes, I got it from whereis php

Comment: Remove everything from the `>` onwards and post the results?

Comment: When i remove it, the browser keeps loading without any output, content  of script.php is : "<?php
echo 'Hello World!';
?>"

Answer (score 1):

try

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/php -f /home/site/public_html/script.php > /home/site/log.txt &');
```

or type

```
whereis php
```

and use the path given.

Comment: I tried shell_exec('/usr/bin/php -f /home/site/public_html/script.php > /home/websity/log.txt &'); and i got the same output, also from output it seems that php is executed but couldn't find the file script.php

Comment: could you give the output? Also could you "ls -l /home/site/public_html/script.php" to ensure it exists.

Comment: I am calling the script through browser, and the output file is as i mentioned first "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.23
Content-type: text/html", also the file script.php already exists and content is "<?php
echo 'Hello World!';
?>"

Comment: OK its probably a permissions issue. Check the username that apache runs under assuming you are running apache (usually www-data). Make sure www-data has execute permissions on the folder the file is in, and is readable by www-data (or whichever user apache runs under).

Comment: I am using suPHP, so the user is the same user of website, and it has execute permission on the folder.

Comment: so executing a command line PHP command seems to output HTTP headers into a file? Maybe this is related to suPHP could you try to disable it temporarily?